# How to make axes text more bold in R - heatplots?

Tags: r

On x and Y axis my labels looks dull, how do I make them **BOLD**?
Some suggestions would be great.

```
heatplot(dsgse4, showCategory = 30, foldChange = mcmc)
```

[image: heatplot]

Comment: What package is `heatplot` from? It looks like a standard ggplot, so you could try adding `+ theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))`

Comment: ggplot2. works great.